# What action JRPG is this screenshot from?

Tags: game-identification

Can someone please tell me what game this screenshot is from?

[image: Screenshot]

Here are the video and timestamp (15:16) the screenshot was taken from:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The video must refer to the English language version PS4/PS5 port of [***The Legend of Heroes: Trails through Daybreak***](https://www.gematsu.com/2023/09/the-legend-of-heroes-trails-through-daybreak-coming-west-in-summer-2024-for-ps5-ps4-switch-and-pc/The_Legend_of_Heroes_Kuro_no_Kiseki/) (or [***Kuro No Kiseki***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Heroes:_Trails_Through_Daybreak)), [said to be released in 2024](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Heroes:_Trails_Through_Daybreak#Development_and_release).

The original Japanese game was released in 2022, but the English version and a Nintendo Switch port have been announced to be released in 2024.
The game is part of the [*Trails*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trails_(series)) series, itself a part of the [*The Legend of Heroes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Legend_of_Heroes) game series.

The same enemies from your screenshot can be seen in this animated gif (which was posted [here](https://tenor.com/view/kiseki-kuro-no-kiseki-rixia-mao-rixia-cao-lee-gif-22851721)):

[image]

Here is a higher quality screenshot from Steam from [*Kuro No Kiseki*](https://store.steampowered.com/app/1811950/The_Legend_of_Heroes_Kuro_no_Kiseki/):

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I never played a Trails game, but I thought they were just turn based, so I assumed it couldn't be one of those.  I guess this one is a hybrid.